# Propagate exceptions in Python 2 conserving the backtrace

Tags: python, exception

I have a Python code where I want to catch all possible exceptions and rise my own custom exception, but conserving as much information as possible.

In Python 3, there is a construct `raise from` that does more or less what I want

```
def function():
    return 1 / 0

class MyException(Exception):
    pass

try:
    function()
except Exception as err:
    raise MyException(err) from err
```

Output is

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "capture.py", line 9, in <module>
   function()
  File "capture.py", line 3, in function
    return 1 / 0
ZeroDivisionError: division by zero

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "capture.py", line 11, in <module>
    raise MyException(err) from err
__main__.MyException: division by zero
```

Is there a way to obtain similar result in Python 2?

So, for future reference, the answer is yes.
Given the answer in the linked question, what I want can be achieved with the following code

```
import sys

def function():
    return 1 / 0

class MyException(Exception):
    pass

try:
    function()
except Exception as err:
    raise MyException, err, sys.exc_info()[2]
```